# Cross Products and Commutators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, operators, lie-algebra

For non-commuting vector operators we have in general
$$\mathbf{A}\times \mathbf{B}= - \mathbf{B}\times \mathbf{A} +\sum_{ijk} \epsilon_{ijk} \big[ A_i,\,B_j\big]\hat{\mathbf{k}}  $$

For the case $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{B}$ this becomes
$$ \mathbf{A}\times \mathbf{A}= - \mathbf{A}\times \mathbf{A} +\sum_{ijk} \epsilon_{ijk} \big[ A_i,\,A_j\big]\hat{\mathbf{k}} $$
This would imply
$$2\left(\mathbf{A}\times \mathbf{A}\right)_k = \sum_{ij} \epsilon_{ijk}\big[ A_i,\,A_j\big]  $$

Sources give the angular momentum commuator relations as
$$\mathbf{J}\times \mathbf{J} = i\mathbf{J}$$
But we also know them as 
$$[J_i,J_j] = i\sum_{k}\epsilon_{ijk}J_k $$
I am curious about the connection these two equations. Can we derive the 2nd from the 1st? There is some discussion of it [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-05-quantum-physics-ii-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT8_05F13_Chap_09.pdf) on page 8. The 1st comes easily from the 2nd. I am not sure about the discussion of reversibility. What does $\mathbf{J}\times \mathbf{J} = i\mathbf{J}$ imply about $[J_i,J_j]$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
\big( {\bf J} \times {\bf J} \big)_i = \epsilon_{ijk} J_j J_k = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_{ijk} [ J_j , J_k ] =  i J_i~. 
$$
Contract both sides with $\epsilon_{ipq}$. Then,
$$
i \epsilon_{ipq} J_i = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_{ijk} \epsilon_{ipq} [ J_j , J_k ] = \frac{1}{2} ( \delta_{jp} \delta_{kq} - \delta_{jq} \delta_{kp} ) [ J_j , J_k ] = [ J_p , J_q ]~. 
$$
Thus, we conclude
$$
[ J_i , J_j ] = i \epsilon_{ijk} J_k ~. 
$$